# Is the Hicksian demand curve steeper or flatter than Slutsky demand?

Tags: consumer-theory, slutsky-equation

Putting price on the vertical axis and quantity on the horizontal axis, is the Slutsky demand steeper or flatter than the Hicksian demand curve? If I calculate the Slutsky and Hicksian substitution effects for a normal good (Cobb-Douglas), I get Slutsky substitution effect greater than Hicksian substitution effect. Shouldn' t that mean that Hicksian demand is steeper than Slutsky? I have seen the opposite being drawn in some lecture notes.

[image]

Comment: Extent in elasticity doesn't matter in case of Normal Good.